# Including mathtools changes page layout with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, books, mathtools, layout

I have a package `s5paper` (below) not written by me that sets up a Swedish paper format S5 with a page layout with margins and such. But when I build with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex the page layout changes depending on whether `mathtools` is included or not. Could you help me figure out what is going on?

## Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{s5paper}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Test}
  \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Built document WITH mathtools]

[image: Built document WITHOUT mathtools]

## s5paper.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{s5paper}[2006/08/28]
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{keyval}

% Paper size
\newdimen\extra@margin
\extra@margin0pt
\define@key{s5paper}{margin}{\setlength{\extra@margin}{#1}}

\def\ProcessOptionsWithKV#1{%
  \let\@tempc\relax
  \let\@tempa\@empty
  \@for\CurrentOption:=\@classoptionslist\do{%
    \@ifundefined{KV@#1@\CurrentOption}%
    {}%
    {%
      \edef\@tempa{\@tempa,\CurrentOption,}%
      \@expandtwoargs\@removeelement\CurrentOption
        \@unusedoptionlist\@unusedoptionlist
    }%
  }%
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \noexpand\setkeys{#1}{%
      \@tempa\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}%
    }%
  }%
  \@tempa
  \let\CurrentOption\@empty
  \AtEndOfPackage{\let\@unprocessedoptions\relax}}
\ProcessOptionsWithKV{s5paper}


\setlength\paperheight {242mm}
\setlength\paperwidth  {165mm}%
\advance\paperheight2\extra@margin
\advance\paperwidth2\extra@margin
\hoffset 0in
\voffset 0in
\topmargin 8mm
\advance\topmargin -1in
\advance\topmargin\extra@margin
\oddsidemargin 24mm
\advance\oddsidemargin -1in
\advance\oddsidemargin\extra@margin
\evensidemargin 21mm
\advance\evensidemargin-1in
\advance\evensidemargin\extra@margin
\headheight 10mm
\headsep 8mm
\footskip 9mm
\marginparwidth 17mm
\marginparsep 2mm
\marginparpush 1em

\setlength{\textheight}{190mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth-2in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\evensidemargin}%

\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined\else
  \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
  \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\fi
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get the same result with and without `mathtools`. I'm using an up-to-date TeX Live 2022 with `mathtools` 2022/06/29 v1.29.

Comment: @cabohah I see now that it only happens with xelatex and lualatex

Comment: your sty sets the mediabox correctly only for pdflatex. But mathtools loads graphics and then the mediabox is correct also for the other engines.

Comment: BTW: You could also use [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with option `paperwidth=165mm,paperheight=242mm` or `papersize={165mm,242mm}` to setup the correct paper size.  Margins can also be changed using `geometry`. In this case the mediabox will be set correctly with other engines too. Something like extra margins can also be done using `geometry` (see the difference of layout and paper in the manual).

Comment: @cabohah That's the [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665274/replace-old-package-with-geometry-settings) :-)

Comment: Good luck with your thesis work! 