# Replace old paper layout package with geometry settings

Tags: geometry, books

I have an old package that sets up a Swedish paper format (S5) with a page layout with margins and such. From what I understand [it only sets the mediabox correctly only with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665265/including-mathtools-changes-page-layout-with-xelatex-and-lualatex?noredirect=1#comment1654250_665265).

To me this looks like an excellent time to use the [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. But my attempt to translate the code to package options doesn't work. Also, I can't see `\marginparpush` in the documentation to `geometry`.

Can you help?

## s5paper.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{s5paper}[2006/08/28 author: Pedher Johansson]
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{keyval}

% Paper size
\newdimen\extra@margin
\extra@margin0pt
\define@key{s5paper}{margin}{\setlength{\extra@margin}{#1}}

\def\ProcessOptionsWithKV#1{%
  \let\@tempc\relax
  \let\@tempa\@empty
  \@for\CurrentOption:=\@classoptionslist\do{%
    \@ifundefined{KV@#1@\CurrentOption}%
    {}%
    {%
      \edef\@tempa{\@tempa,\CurrentOption,}%
      \@expandtwoargs\@removeelement\CurrentOption
        \@unusedoptionlist\@unusedoptionlist
    }%
  }%
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \noexpand\setkeys{#1}{%
      \@tempa\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}%
    }%
  }%
  \@tempa
  \let\CurrentOption\@empty
  \AtEndOfPackage{\let\@unprocessedoptions\relax}}
\ProcessOptionsWithKV{s5paper}


\setlength\paperheight {242mm}          %Modified by Ettore from 238
\setlength\paperwidth  {165mm}%
\advance\paperheight2\extra@margin
\advance\paperwidth2\extra@margin
\hoffset 0in
\voffset 0in
\topmargin 8mm
\advance\topmargin -1in
\advance\topmargin\extra@margin
\oddsidemargin 24mm
\advance\oddsidemargin -1in
\advance\oddsidemargin\extra@margin
\evensidemargin 21mm
\advance\evensidemargin-1in
\advance\evensidemargin\extra@margin
\headheight 10mm
\headsep 8mm
\footskip 9mm
\marginparwidth 17mm
\marginparsep 2mm
\marginparpush 1em

\setlength{\textheight}{190mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth-2in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin-\evensidemargin}%

\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined\else
  \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
  \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\fi
```

## My attempt

```
\documentclass{book}
% \usepackage{s5paper}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=242mm+0pt*2,
  paperwidth=165mm+0pt*2,
  layouthoffset=0mm,
  layoutvoffset=0mm,
  top=8mm-1in-0pt,
  inner=24mm-1in-0pt,
  outer=21mm-1in-0pt,
  headheight=10mm,
  headsep=8mm,
  footskip=9mm,
  marginparwidth=17mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,
  height=190mm,
  width=120mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Test}
  \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result with s5paper]

[image: Result with my flawed geometry settings]

Comment: `geometry` does the `-1in` for the offset of TeX's paper origin automatically. So you have to omit it. `\marginparpush` can be and needs to be set manually, because it is not really a page layout parameter but parameter of consecutive margin notes.

Comment: @cabohah While removing the `-1in` from `top`, `inner`, and `outer` is a great improvement, it doesn't go all the way :-/ And `\setlength{\marginparpush}{1em}` is apparently not really related.

Comment: @cabohah Eyeballing gives that `top=8mm+0.709in-0pt` is about right. But it would be nice to know the root cause of that magic number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah) [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665274/replace-old-paper-layout-package-with-geometry-settings#comment1654259_665274)

- "`geometry` does the `-1in` for the offset of TeX's paper origin automatically"
- `\marginparpush` is not part of the page layout and so needs to be set separately

Finally, the [magic number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665274/replace-old-paper-layout-package-with-geometry-settings#comment1654299_665274) `0.709in` was simply `\headheight+\headsep` as this is included in `geometry`'s definition of the header (as per [Figure 1](https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf#figure.1) in the documentation).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\newdimen\extramargin% Take care of the `s5paper` package's option `margin`
\extramargin0pt
\usepackage[
  paperheight=242mm+2\extramargin,
  paperwidth=165mm+2\extramargin,
  layouthoffset=0mm,
  layoutvoffset=0mm,
  top=8mm+10mm+8mm+\extramargin,% Add \headheight and \headsep
  inner=24mm+\extramargin,
  outer=21mm+\extramargin,
  headheight=10mm,
  headsep=8mm,
  footskip=9mm,
  marginparwidth=17mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,
  height=190mm,
  width=120mm,
]{geometry}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{1em}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Test}
  \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```